# Prove $a\cdot 2^x+b\cdot 3^x+c\cdot 7^x$ has at most two real solutions for $a,b,c\ne 0$

Tags: real-analysis, exponentiation

> Prove $a\cdot 2^x+b\cdot 3^x+c\cdot 7^x$ has at most two real solutions.

I can prove a variant with two terms in the following way:
$$a\cdot 2^x+b\cdot 3^x=0$$
$$-\frac{a}{b}=\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^x$$

If $a,b$ have the same parity there are zero solutions, and if they don't there is one (real) solution.

But I can't expand that method to more terms. How can I approach this problem?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? 1. Out of {x, a, b, c}, which variable(s) are you solving for? 2. Out of {x, a, b, c}, which variables(s) have to be integers? (Usually when one says a variable is "real", it implies it doesn't have to be an integer, but you talk about its parity.) Are there any other restrictions, e.g. nonnegative? 3. I am assuming you want to make the expression equal to 0, is that right? (Currently it's not an equation because it has no equals sign.) 4. Can you explain why there are no solutions if a, b have the same parity and state what is the solution if they don't?

Comment: That is an expression, not an equation. So it doesn't have "solutions". It should be "Prove $a\cdot 2^x+b\cdot 3^x+c\cdot 7^x=0$ has at most two real solutions."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Either I missed the title the first time or it was edited later. This note can be skipped.

**Note:** you would need that at least one of them is nonzero. Otherwise, you have infinitely many roots. Even your "solution" for the case of two terms is missing this. However, the conclusion for the case of two terms *is* correct if you require one of $a$ or $b$ to be nonzero.

We shall assume that $a$ and $b$ are nonzero. Else, this reduces to a two terms case anyway.

---

The question is equivalent to solving 
$$a\alpha^x + b\beta^x = -c$$
for $\alpha = 2/7$ and $\beta = 3/7$.

---

Define $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ as 
$$f(x) := a\alpha^x + b\beta^x + c.$$

We then have

$$f'(x) = a(\ln\alpha)\alpha^x + b(\ln\beta)\beta^x.$$

Now, since $a \neq 0 \neq b$, we have that $f'$ has at most one real root. (By the two terms case.)
This, in turn, implies that $f$ has at most two real roots. (Use Rolle's theorem to disprove the existence of more than two roots.)

---

This method can be extended for more number of terms as well!

Comment: I think you must mean "we have that $f'(x)$ has at most one real root."

Comment: @TonyK: yes, indeed! Thanks, have fixed it.